# Unexpected deferred object's behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Could anyoune please clarify what's wrong with the code below ( have read a lot of docs and examples, but still got no idea what's going on)

```
function t() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        d.resolve();
    }, 5000);
    return d.promise();
}
function test() {
    var dd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax("/echo/json/").done(function() {
        dd = t();
        dd.done(function() { alert(" dd.done inside ajax")});
    });
    dd.done(function() { alert(" dd.done outside ajax")});
}
test();
```

the output was (in ~ 5 s):

```
"dd.done inside ajax:"
```

Why second .done  is not working?

Comment: Have you popped open the developer console to check for any errors?

Comment: no errors, but strangely, first console.log ( replaced alert and url for run in browser) output has doubled. W.T.H.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second alert is never called because the original deferred you assign to the variable `dd` is never resolved and thus its `.done()` handler is never called.

You create a deferred and assign it to `dd` here:

```
var dd = $.Deferred();
```

And, then you set up a `.done()` handler with this:

```
dd.done(function() { alert(" dd.done outside ajax")});
```

But, when your ajax function finishes, you assign a different promise to the variable `dd` with this line:

```
dd = t();
```

And, thus nothing ever resolves the original promise so its `.done()` handler is never called.

---

I'd suggest this design instead:

```
function t() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        d.resolve();
    }, 5000);
    return d.promise();
}
function test() {
    return $.ajax("/echo/json/").then(function() {
        console.log("ajax call done");
        return t();
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("after timer");
    });
}

test().then(function() {
    console.log("everything done");
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/atafc5hj/

This illustrates the following concepts which are useful to know:

1. Using the promise already returned from `$.ajax()` rather than creating your own.
2. Chaining another activity to that promise.
3. Returning another promise from the `.then()` handler to make the sequence wait for that promise too.
4. Returning the chained promise from the main function so you can see when everything is done.

---

Comment: Great, now i saw things clearly, special thanks for suggested solution which  facilitates understanding of a subject and saves me from weekend's headache

Comment: But...) there's still one thing seem unclear to me. I noticed that you used .then() for assigning callbacks instead of .done().
 I run your code ( worked perfectly, thanks again) unchanged except using .done instead of .then here:

    **return $.ajax("/echo/json/").done(function() {

which results in immediate execution of 2nd callback ("after timer"), as if it was assigned to already resolved deferred object.

Comment: I use .then() because it is the promise standard way of doing things, not a jQuery invention.

Comment: thank you, so it looks like .done() is not useful for chaining promises

Comment: @PaulJanssen - yes, only `.then()` supports full-borne chaining by returning new promises from within the callbacks.  Once you learn how `.then()` works in standards-compliant promises, I've found no reason to ever use `.done()` with jQuery again.  Plus, I see value in coding the standards-compliant way (when possible) which is to use `.then()`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at `test()`:

```
function test() {
    var dd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax("/echo/json/").done(function() {
        dd = t();
        dd.done(function() { alert(" dd.done inside ajax")});
    });
    dd.done(function() { alert(" dd.done outside ajax")});
}
test();
```

Local variable `dd` is initialized to a new jQuery Deferred object. Then, an ajax operation is started, and given a "done" callback that'll call the other test function `t()`.

The `$.ajax()` call will return essentially immediately, long before its `.done()` callback is run. Right after that, another `.done()` callback is established for that Deferred instance created at the beginning of the function.

Now, when the ajax "done" callback runs, the value of `dd` — the initially-created Deferred object — will be *overwritten* with the Promise returned from `t()`.  Eventually that `.done()` callback will be run, but nothing ever resolves the first Deferred instance, so that "outside" callback never happens.

Comment: Thanks. I see where my fault is

Answer (score 1):

Because that deferred object is not resolved. You are creating 2 deferred objects and resolving one of them.